# Is there a way in snowflake to get a table of 10 precentiles?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like that:

| userID | time_spent | Dollars_Paid | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 50 | 5 | 02/06/2022 |
| 1002 | 70 | 10 | 02/06/2022 |
| 1004 | 20 | 1 | 02/06/2022 |
| 1005 | 30 | 4 | 02/06/2022 |

and I want to calculate the 10,20,30,40,50...90,99 percentile of Time Spent, and then get the AVG dollars paid for each precentile.

lets say, something like this -

| Precentile | time_spent | avg dollar | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 4 | 2.3 | 02/06/2022 |
| 20 | 20 | 4.5 | 02/06/2022 |
| 30 | 35 | 6.4 | 02/06/2022 |
| 40 | 50 | 6.2 | 02/06/2022 |

How can I do that?

Comment: edited so the table will be visible

Comment: to calculate percentage you need to implement formula `(value/total value)×100`, in your case `time_spent` is `value` but you are missing a field for `total value`.

Comment: total value is sum(time_spent) per day

Comment: You could use a `SUM()` with window function to get the total value.  That'll give you a percent for every record.  You'd have to bucket those values and then take an average over those buckets with a window function, as well.  Probably need at least 1 CTE to do this in one query.

Comment: Can you be specific about the formula used to produce the second table?